# Count like values in keys in Collection

Tags: java, json

I want to count how many blank values of a particular key exist in a Java collection.

Here is my object:

```
public class Widget {
    private String name;
    private String location;
    private String lastUsedBy;
    //getters and setters omitted
}
```

I get a series of these in via json, and I turn them into a collection like so:

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Widget>>(){}.getType();
Collection<Widget> response =  new Gson().fromJson(json, collectionType);
```

Works perfectly, happy with it - however now, I need to count the total amount of widgets in my collection where lastUsedBy attribute is "";

That is, it's unset currently. That way I can determine my total Widgets (response.size()) and deduct how many widgets that have "lastUsedBy" set, in order to get what I actually want - which is how many widgets have been used.

I keep googling the wrong thing, so I've ended up looking at a lot of things about lists and maps, but I can't convey what I need. Example json:

```
[{"name": "one", "location": "upstairs", "lastUsedBy": "Gary"}, 
{"name": "one", "location": "downstairs", "lastUsedBy": "James"}, 
{"name": "one", "location": "outside", "lastUsedBy": ""}]
```

In this case I'd expect to find that response.size() is 3. Then if I could work out how to do it, Collections.filterOnLastUsedByEmpty() = 1. Thus 3 - 1 = 2.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to define your logic in your method, for example:

```
    // java 1.8
List<Widget> filterOnLastUsedByEmpty(Collection<Widget> widgets) {
    return widgets.stream().filter(w -> w.lastUsedBy == null || w.lastUsedBy.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

// java < 1.8
List<Widget> filterOnLastUsedByEmpty(Collection<Widget> widgets) {
    List<Widget> r = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Widget widget : widgets) {
        if (widget.lastUsedBy == null || widget.lastUsedBy.isEmpty()) {
            r.add(widget);
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use streams as follows:

```
long count = response
                    .stream()
                    .filter(r -> r.getLastUsedBy() == null || u.getLastUsedBy().isEmpty())
                    .count();
```